# How do I create a new customer segment in Websphere Commerce using only DB2 database queries?

Tags: database, db2, websphere-commerce

How can I add a new customer segment using only the database?  I know how to create customer segments in CMC, but I'm looking to automate the process of adding, say, hundreds of user segments by writing a script to do it for me.  However, I can't find any information on how to create a new customer segment using only DB2 database queries.

Is there a way to create a new customer segment using nothing but DB2 database queries?

Comment: What am I missing?  Why wouldn't you just insert into the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend that you use SQL directly to create customer segments, as this makes generation of primary keys and updates of the KEYS table your responsibility. And once you take that on, Murphy's Law states that you'll get something wrong.

Your question asks how to create "hundreds of user segments". However, I'm not sure if that's what you meant, or if you meant that you had hundreds of *users* to add to existing segments.

If you're talking about loading hundreds of users, then I'd refer you to 
[this article in the Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.data.doc/tasks/tmlloadcustseg.htm) that explains how you can use the `MemberGroupMemberMediator` to load segments from e-mail addresses.

If you truly mean to create *segments* by data load, I'd refer you to [this Knowledge Center article](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.data.doc/refs/rmlmembergroupex.htm?lang=en) that shows how to create member groups. A customer segment is a member group with a particular usage type.

For reference, these are the tables involved:

- MBRGRP: The base group (segment) definintion
- MBRGRPCOND: This is used to define the condition if it is a rule-based segment (e.g. "all shoppers over the age of 25")
- MBRGRPDESC: The NLS description (name, etc) of the segment
- MBRGRPMBR: For manually defined segments, this defines the members (relationship to MEMBER table)
- MBRGRPTYPE: The type of the member group (e.g. "CustomerGroup")
- MBRGRPUSG: The usage code for the member group (e.g. "GeneralPurpose")

Answer (score 0):

What version fixpack / fep are you working with?  Have you read http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.management-center.doc/tasks/tsbctsegbatch.htm?lang=en

Comment: This is more suited to be a comment on the question rather than an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Technically, changing the DB2 database directly is not officially supported. There are things like stagingprop that depend on certain actions happening in certain ways. For example, primary keys of any rows in any table that is a part of stagingprop cannot be updated. CMC will instead do this for you as a delete and an insert when you make the change through CMC.

That said, I've seen unsupported methods like this used to update/change/create data in WebSphere Commerce databases. I don't have the information specific to how to do this for customer segments. I just caution you that it is dangerous when changing the DB2 database directly, so be sure you have backups and evaluate the impact on other processes like stagingprop or dbclean very carefully.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to claim that the suggested scenario is _unsupported_. However, you are absolutely right that it is recommended to use built-in methods, such as massload, dataload, or Management Center itself. The important point is to ensure that non-natural primary keys are generated correctly and that the `KEYS` table is updated accordingly.